# XSLTProcessor.transformToDocument returns null

Tags: javascript, typescript, xslt

I'm having some problems with using XSLTProcessor in my typescript code. The `transformToDocument` always returns null with no apparent reason. Here is my code:

```
private GenerateForm() {
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(this.NodeFromString(formTransform));
    var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(this.NodeFromString(schema));
    console.log(resultDocument);
    $("#form-position").append(resultDocument);
}

private NodeFromString(xmlString: string): Node {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    console.log(doc.documentElement);
    return doc.documentElement;
}
```

The `formTransform` and `schema` strings contain full representations of those 2 files imported to string. Here is the transformation I want to achieve: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser implementations of XSLT support XSLT 1.0 only and don't support or ignore XSLT 2 features like `xsl:function` you are trying to use.

Comment: Oh I haven't realized that functions are XSLT2 feature. Since it was only returning null I had no idea why.

Comment: Trying to develop and test and debug XSLT 1 run in the browser is rather difficult, I suggest you first develop and test outside of the browser with an XSLT 1.0 processor. I don't think the xsltfiddle is a good debug environment but if you choose an XSLT 1 processor like XslCompiledTransform there, like I have done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzb/2, you at least get an error message "'xsl:function' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:transform' element." giving a meaningful hint.